# Remove foreach last comma PHP

Tags: php

How to remove last comma from the output of a `foreach()` loop?

Can someone please help modify this code for me.

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `stage5` ORDER BY `stage5`.`lenght` DESC');
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $r) {
     echo $r['lenght'], ",";
}
```

This prints 
`105.4,102.1,`

Below would be correct 
`105.4,102.1`

I have read many posts related to this but, I can't get it working and I don't get it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, I did know there is other posts, but being beginner with PHP, I tried many options and Googled but didn't get it working. So I posted my actual code on question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to solve this is to not echo out the commas in the `foreach` loop.  Put the data you want to echo into an array, then use `implode`.

```
$output = array();
foreach($result as $r) {
    $output[] = $r['lenght'];
}

echo implode(',', $output);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just take a functional approach:

```
<?php
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
echo implode(',', array_column($result, 'length'));
```

Note that [`array_column()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) requires PHP 5.5+.