# Sorting list by alphabetical order, with special case for certain starting letter

Tags: python, list, sorting

Given a list of strings, I want to return a list with the strings in sorted order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' first.

For example:

```
['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
```

Should yield:

```
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

I know it can be done by making 2 lists and sorting each of them before combining them, but I'm not sure how to write the condition in which 'x' is the first character.

Comment: and what did you tried to code?

Comment: rsm - I'm actually pretty new at this, so I didn't know what to do. I searched this and other sites for a good answer, but couldn't find any, so I posted this here, hoping to get some assistance. Thanks for all your answers, people! (and to Will, for editing my question).

Answer (score 9):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) accepts optional `key` keyword argument. That is the function used to get sort key, and the return value of the function is used to compare instead of the original items.

```
>>> words = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
>>> sorted(words, key=lambda word: (word[0] != 'x', word))
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

used `word[0] != 'x'`; which return `False` (0) for word starts with `x`, `True` (1) for other words; resulting words start with `x` come first.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a particular case in your key method: if starts with x, return a truncated string starting with "0" so it will appear first, but will be still sorted after "x".

```
z=['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']

z.sort(key=lambda x : "0"+x if x.startswith("x") else x)
print(z)
```

yields:

```
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
words = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
result = [i for _, i in sorted((word[0]!='x', word) for word in words)]
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation to your code?

Comment: using `_` as a variable name is strange for sure. I didn't even know that it worked. Cryptic as hell! Please explain that the returned key is a tuple, and sorting on tuples works by trying first value, and so on which explains why it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sorted(['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'],
           key=lambda x: (not x.startswith('x'), x))
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

The [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin returns a new, stable-sorted `list()` of each element in the input iterable, sorted by `key`. `key`, in this case, is a [*lambda expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) (basically a "mini-function") which transforms or converts each element in the input list into a sortable value.

In this case, our lambda expression sorts each word in the list by a `tuple()` which contains `False` or `True` indicating whether or not the word starts with `"x"`, followed by the word itself. Since `False` is "smaller" than `True`, the words that start with `"x"` appear first, and everything else is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation to your code? This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Comment: @Will I believe it's self-explanatory. You don't?

Comment: The code does speak for itself to me, as an experienced Python engineer. However, new users who stumble across this may not understand `lambdas`, `sorted()` or `str.startswith()`. Additionally, adding plain-English explanation is just a part of SO's culture (not sure if an actual requirement). I'll add the type of brief explanation I'm talking about as an example; feel free to improve.

Comment: Ok, check out my edit :) Remember, your audience doesn't always know what you or I know and take for granted.

Comment: @Will I guess it might help some people, but I wouldn't have the patience to preemptively explain such basic stuff. I'd say *"my audience"* is the people who couldn't or wouldn't come up with my code, but *can* understand it, at least after playing with it or looking stuff up. But ok, I'll just try harder to stay away from SO.

Comment: Seems to be a bit of a toxic attitude. Regardless, code-only answers pop up in the review queue, so you can just include a single sentence of explanation (that isn't "Try this:") and they won't pop up in the review queue. From your stats, it looks like you've helped a lot of people here and it would be a shame to see you spend less time on SO. I never voted to delete your post, and in fact upvoted it. My suggestions are only meant as constructive criticism, and you certainly don't need to add as much explanation as I did. Please don't let my suggestions make you not want to be here. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Will Well, I'm sure you could've explained in even much more detail, but you didn't, right? You stopped at some level, just like I did. Our levels just differ. And it's not like I don't want to explain anything, I also did write a [fairly long answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38164742/1672429) the same day. But don't worry, the reason I'm trying to stay away is just that I have much more important stuff that I should be doing instead.

Comment: Right, the only takeaway here is that if it doesn't have a sentence of text, it gets popped in the review queue. Your other answer is excellent, upvoted that as well :)

Comment: Here's an example of [one of my very short ones](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37711234/145279) that is mostly code-only. So you're absolutely right; you don't need significant explanation in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it using the built-in `list.sort()` and then use list comprehension to get the output you desire as follows:

```
sl = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
sl.sort()
sl = [el for el in sl if el.startswith("x")]+[el for el in sl if not el.startswith("x")]
```