# File data to array is using a lot of memory

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I'm taking a large text file with tab separated values and adding them to an array.

When I run my code on a 32 Mb file, python memory consumption goes through the roof; using around 500 Mb RAM.

I need to be able to run this code for a 2 GB file, and possibly even larger files.

My current code is:

```
markers = []

def parseZeroIndex():
    with open('chromosomedata') as zeroIndexes:
        for line in zeroIndexes:
            markers.append(line.split('\t'))

parseZeroIndex()
```

Running this code against my 2 GB file is not possible as is. The files look like this:

```
per1    1029292 string1 euqye
per1    1029292 string2 euqys
```

My questions are:

What is using all this memory?

What is a more efficient way to do this memory wise?

Comment: First of all, you should always use the `csv` module. It will probably better handle how the file is read and cached.

Comment: Overhead data for Python objects. Are there many duplicate values, or are they pretty much all different? And do you really need to hold it all in RAM?

Comment: And BTW, it could be that the answer lies in the way you define `markers` or call `parseZeroIndex`. You may consider posting that too.

Comment: Do you really need all the data stored together at once ?

Comment: I actually need it all stored at once, yes - will be running it on a cluster in the end but I'd still like it to perform properly on my machine. No two lines in the file are the same.

Comment: What else are you doing with the data? I doubt just reading into a list of lists would take up that much memory.

Comment: @hallizh When I asked about duplicate/different values, I meant like your "Value 1a", not complete lines. So are there duplicates in those values?

Comment: About Python object overhead: `import sys; print(sys.getsizeof(""))` shows me that even the empty string takes 25 bytes, while "a" takes 26 and "ä" takes 38.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sorry, yes. there is a lot of duplicated values in the fields, even though no two lines are the same.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This is all the source code stripped down to this. Running this with a 2 GB file on my 16 GB RAM computer crashes it.

Comment: @hallizh Are your values all strings?

Comment: @hallizh Please try what I suggest in my answer and tell how much RAM it takes with that.

Comment: Is it possible to share the 32mb file? There are probably much better ways to do what you but without knowing exactly what that is then it is going to be hard to suggest a significantly better approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, the second column is always a number.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, sorry, I can't share the file. I updated the question and added two lines from it with changed values.

Comment: @hallizh, what is the end goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### "What is using all this memory?"

There's overhead for Python objects. See how many bytes some strings actually take:

Python 2:

```
>>> import sys
>>> map(sys.getsizeof, ('', 'a', u'ä'))
[21, 22, 28]
```

Python 3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> list(map(sys.getsizeof, ('', 'a', 'ä')))
[25, 26, 38]
```

---

### "What is a more efficient way to do this memory wise?"

In comments you said there are lots of duplicate values, so [**string interning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) (storing only one copy of each distinct string value) might help a lot. Try this:

Python 2:

```
            markers.append(map(intern, line.rstrip().split('\t')))
```

Python 3:

```
            markers.append(list(map(sys.intern, line.rstrip().split('\t'))))
```

Note I also used `line.rstrip()` to remove the trailing `\n` from the line.

---

**Experiment**

I tried

```
>>> x = [str(i % 1000) for i in range(10**7)]
```

and

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = [sys.intern(str(i % 1000)) for i in range(10**7)]
```

in Python 3. The first one takes 355 MB (looking at the process in Windows Task Manager). The second one takes only 47 MB. Furthermore:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(x)
40764032
>>> sum(map(sys.getsizeof, x[:1000]))
27890
```

So 40 MB is for the list referencing the strings (no surprise, as there are ten million references of four bytes each). And the strings themselves total only 27 **K**B.

---

**Further improvements**

As seen in the experiment, much of your RAM usage might be not from the strings but from your list object(s). Both your `markers` list object as well as all those list objects representing your rows. Especially if you're using 64-bit Python, which I suspect you do.

To reduce that overhead, you could use tuples instead of lists for your rows, as they're more light-weight:

```
sys.getsizeof(['a', 'b', 'c'])
48
>>> sys.getsizeof(('a', 'b', 'c'))
40
```

I estimate your 2 GB file has 80 million rows, so that would save 640 MB RAM. Perhaps more if you run 64-bit Python.

Another idea: If all your rows have the same number of values (I assume three), then you could ditch those 80 million row list objects and use a one-dimensional list of the 240 million string values instead. You'd just have to access it with `markers[3*i+j]` instead of `markers[i][j]`. And it could save a few GB RAM.

Comment: This improved my solution significantly, thank you very much :)

Still looking for ways to improve it though, 2 GB file uses around 8 GB of RAM at the moment (was approx 20 GB).

Comment: @hallizh Check out the experiment I added at the end and notice that my list takes a lot of memory, too. From your example data I estimate that you have 80 million rows, and `sys.getsizeof(['a', 'b', 'c'])` shows that a list with three string references takes 48 bytes. And 80 million times 48 bytes is about 3.6 GB.

Comment: @hallizh Oh and... please tell me what you get for `sys.getsizeof(['a', 'b', 'c'])`. Given that you're able to use 8 GB, I suspect you might be running 64-bit Python?

Comment: @hallizh If your rows don't need to be lists, you could use tuples instead: `markers.append(tuple(...))`. Tuples are more light-weight, a three-tuple takes me 40 bytes instead of the list's 48 bytes.

Comment: @hallizh Another idea: If all your rows have the same number of values (I assume three), then you could ditch those ~80 million row list objects and use a one-dimensional list of ~240 million instead. You'd just have to access it with `markers[3*i+j]` instead of `markers[i][j]`. And it could save a few GB RAM.

Comment: I'm getting 88, so that's probably 64-bit python. Very informative post, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @hallizh Yeah. Then I estimate that 7.5 of those 8 GB are for the lists, not the strings. Can you try `markers.extend` instead of `markers.append`? That'll do the one-dimension idea, so you won't be able to use it as before, but I'm curious how much RAM that takes then.